# batch file to pass variables and change TXT files

Tags: batch-file

I need to change the contents of a TXT file, through a variable passed in batch file.

follows:

```
[00010001]
Name = 192.168.1.141
Port = 2046
[GER]
Port=1
Speed=19200
SAM=2
```

I need to change the first 3 lines

Batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal=enabledelayedexpansion
set "nfilial="
set /p "nfilial=Numero do Filial (4 Digitos):"
set "pdvnunber="
set "empresatef="
set /p "empresatef=Numero Empresa TEF (4 Digitos):"
set "iptef="
set /p "iptef=IP Servidor TEF:"
set "portatef="
set /p "portatef=Numero Porta TEF:"
rename scope.ini scope.tmp
for /f %%a in (scope.tmp) do (
  set foo=%%a
  if "!foo:[        ]=!" neq "!foo!" set "foo=[%empresatef%%nfilial%]"
  echo !foo! >> scope.ini) 
del scope.tmp
```

The doubt is, do not know how to spend the remaining parameters, using the same IF, and even when only the first step parameter file already gets all mangled.

follows:

```
[00010001] 
Name 
Port 
[General] 
[GER] 
Port=1 
Speed=19200 
SAM=2
```

same, there is no condition for exchange parameter, the second and third line is also changed.

thank you

Comment: Will it always be the first three lines that you are changing? And could you include what you are trying to change them to?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "nfilial="
set /p "nfilial=Numero do Filial (4 Digitos):"
set "pdvnunber="
set "empresatef="
set /p "empresatef=Numero Empresa TEF (4 Digitos):"
set "iptef="
set /p "iptef=IP Servidor TEF:"
set "portatef="
set /p "portatef=Numero Porta TEF:"
>scope.ini.new (
  echo [%empresatef%%nfilial%]
  echo Name = %iptef%
  echo Port = %portatef%
  for /f "skip=3 delims=" %%A in (scope.ini) do echo %%A
)
move /y scope.ini.new scop.ini >nul
```

If the file does not have any tabs, and the file is <64K lines, then the FOR statement can be replaced by

```
more +3 scope.ini
```

and it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

would limit a character number on the command below? I want to accept only numeric characters and only 2 characters.

```
set "nfilial="
set /p "nfilial=Numero do Filial (2 Digitos):"
for /f "delims=1234567890" %%a in ("%nfilial%") do goto :nfilial
```

Comment: Please ask a new question.